# Remove validator constraint for one single field

Tags: php, symfony

I'm currently wasting a lot of time doing a simple thing.

I want to remove the form checker/validator from symfony in a PARTICULAR field.

Adding this eventlistener to the builder work ok:

```
->addEventListener(
    FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, 
    function (FormEvent $event) { 
        $event->stopPropagation(); 
    }, 
    900
)
```

But it disable the checker for ALL the field, and I only want for one field.

`'required' => false` and `'csrf_protection' => false` don't do the trick

Any help thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Constraints can come from many direction. From your question i am not sure from where the constraint you wanna get rid of come from.

- AppBundle/Resources/validation.[yml|xml|php] look for your entity name and then the field name just comment/remove or modify the constraint if one is found.
- The form type can apply constraint [symfony doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#constraints) if you have a constraint inside your type just open your EntityType.php class and look for the field name and check if there is a option for `constraints`
- `required` options inside type and `<input type="date">` can apply constraint on the client side so make sure it not that kind of constraint you wanna get rid of , you said you removed `required` but maybe a `input type field` persist.
- And then you can have constraint apply inside event from a bundle your are using searching for the error message inside your source files can help you find the code responsible for that hidden constraint

A Symfony constraint should return a human readable error message on failure.

P.S. `required` is not a constraint but can look alike!

Comment: First, Thanks for your reply. 

I have a form with many fields such as name resume ect...
And a entity field called tags.
the user can add tags directly in the field, using Javascript, but the validator 
of symfony say the value is incorrect because it's not really a entity that the user choosen
its a string.
I just want the validator to SKIP any check of this particular field like the  $event->stopPropagation(); do.
Except that the stopPropagation do it for ALL fields, and I just wanna know how to apply it on ONE particular field.
I hope i'm clear, thanks again for your replies

Comment: your problem come from transformer not constraint your form should use this type [collectionType into symfony book](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html) look carefully into the `allow_add,prototype and entry_type` the `entry_type` is very important in your case since it will tell symfony how to transform the data coming form the `prototype` , there event the javascript u need to add new element based on the prototype ;) good reading sir :)